Is there a way for detailed tuning of shadowmap coverage in URP?
We’re experiencing an issue with the URP shadowmap. Our scene contains a number of 3D objects, all located within a small 30x30 unit area. The camera, however, is placed at a significant distance from these objects. To render shadows, we’ve set a large Shadow Distance in the URP settings.
From what we understand, Shadow Distance seems to be the primary parameter controlling the shadowmap coverage area. Since our objects are confined to a small area, and the Shadow Distance is much larger, the objects occupy only a small portion of the shadowmap. This results in low shadow resolution, as shown in the screenshot.
Is there a way to adjust the shadowmap calculation to focus on our objects without altering the Shadow Distance or the position of objects in the scene? Alternatively, do you know of any methods to enhance shadow resolution without increasing the Shadow Resolution setting in URP?

